# Save sql return in a string

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I´m trying to save information from database to a string.

How is this possible with the following code?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT something FROM table");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Is it possible to use this for getting some value from database saved in a `string`?

Comment: Do you need the value of a single row? Do you need the value of a single column? Your question is a bit vague

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, you need to call `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the documentation.

```
string result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

As @ThorstenDittmar pointed out correctly, the casting only works if the value from the database is actually a `string` (or something that can be mapped to it, like `varchar`).

You can use this to be sure:

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

string s = result != null? result.ToString() : null;
```

Or

```
string s = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: This works only if the `object` returned by `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` actually *is* a string. To store *any* object value as string you should use `string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements. Other SQL commands like DDL commands or db administration commands where no result set is returned or the result can be discarded may also be used.

`ExecuteScalar` can be used for `SELECT` statements where only the first field of the first row is needed.

When more fields and/or more rows have to be returned, use `ExecuteReader`.

Example of using `ExecuteReader`:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, loc FROM t WHERE id=@id", conn)) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int nameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("name");
            int locationOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("loc");
            while (reader.Read()) {
                Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Location = {1}",
                    reader.GetString(nameOrdinal),
                    reader.GetString(locationOrdinal));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you *could* use `ExecuteNonQuery` for something that used `return`, `out` or `ref`, but admittedly it would be pretty unusual to do so ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell: Added clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill the records in a `SqlDatareader` or a DataSet/DataTable using `SqlDataAdapter`. Currently you are using `ExecuteNonQuery` which is usually used for `INSERT/UPDATE` statements.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT something FROM table"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

This would return your results from your query in `DataTable`.

If you want to get the results back in a `List<string>` *(since you are requesting a single column from your table and chances are there would be multiple rows)* you can do:

```
List<string> returnedList = new List<string>();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT something FROM table"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                returnedList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["something"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then to get a single string you can do:

```
string singleString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, returnedList);
```

Comment: I can't think of any good reason to involve `SqlDataAdapter` or `DataTable` just to read a `string`... actually, I can *barely* think of any good reason to involve `SqlDataAdapter` or `DataTable` *at all* (caveat: ok, very rare reasons to do with meta-programming and unknown data)

Comment: @MarcGravell, Just trying to show that the records returned would probably be a set. Added an example to get `List<string>` back as well.

Comment: Also I am not sure if OP is really needing a single string back from his/her query.